# What is the projection for point(x,y)?

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

I'm pretty new to `GIS` matter and have no idea how to get the right projection of a point.

What's the projection for point ([582865.200436, 3541848.067073](http://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=2059&t_srs=3857&x=582865.2004360&y=3541848.0670730))?

I have a `.prj` and corresponding `.shp` file. The following, is the content of '.prj' file: `PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_39N",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",51.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]`

I have found `PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"]` in the above content and based on real location of the file (approximately around Iran/Asia) i guess the corresponding projection should be 2059.

How can I find out the correct projection and unit of a '.shp' file out of it's corresponding '.prj' file or any other evidences?

Comment: Pay attention to "UTM ZONE 39N".

Comment: If the shapefile has a `.prj` *and it can be trusted*, then your question is already answered. If what you want is the EPSG SRID, you should **edit** the question to specify that.

Comment: no the content of the file is trusty and i had the answer, but a i'm curious what would it's like if i hadn't `prj` file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do this using both open source (pyproj, gdal, postgis) and commercial libraries (ArcGIS). If it's just a one time work, you could use this service from Boundless:

```
http://prj2epsg.org/search
```

The service is:

> Prj2EPSG is a simple service for converting well-known text projection
>   information from .prj files into standard EPSG codes.

If you paste the contents of the `.prj` file into the search window, you will get back:

`32639 - WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_39N` and the description:

```
Name: WGS 84 / UTM zone 39N 
Scope: Large and medium scale topographic mapping and engineering survey. Remarks: - 
Area of validity: Between 48?E and 54?E; northern hemisphere. Azerbaijan. Bahrain. Islamic Republic of Iran. Iraq. Kazakhstan. Kuwait. Oman. Qatar. Russian Federation. Saudi Arabia. Somalia. Turkmenistan. United Arab Emirates. Yemen.
```

The unit information is already present in the `WKT` (i.e., the contents of the `.prj` file) - `UNIT["Meter",1.0]`.

Comment: actually the unit is the last one `UNIT["Meter",1.0]` metres

Comment: @iant, ah, thanks! Missed that this was connected to the gcs. Updated the answer.